# How to import a Flare animation to native Android project?

Tags: android, animation, flare

I am trying to find a way to import a Flare animation (see Flare here : https://www.2dimensions.com/about-flare) to a native Android project. I have done many researches but I can't find any way to do that.

It is so bad because Flare is really awesome to create animations easily.

Do you know any way to do that exportation ?

Comment: did you find any answer yet?